# SqlDataConnection type provider throws SEHException

Tags: .net, f#, type-providers

I'm using the SqlDataConnection type provider from the FSharp.Data.TypeProviders-package for accessing data from an MSSQL database. I'm getting the following `SEHException`:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: External component has thrown an exception.
   at System.RuntimeType.RuntimeTypeCache.MemberInfoCache`1.PopulateProperties(Filter filter, RuntimeType declaringType, Dictionary`2 csPropertyInfos, Boolean[] usedSlots, ListBuilder`1& list)
   at System.RuntimeType.RuntimeTypeCache.MemberInfoCache`1.PopulateProperties(Filter filter)
   at System.RuntimeType.RuntimeTypeCache.MemberInfoCache`1.GetListByName(Char* pName, Int32 cNameLen, Byte* pUtf8Name, Int32 cUtf8Name, MemberListType listType, CacheType cacheType)
   at System.RuntimeType.RuntimeTypeCache.MemberInfoCache`1.Populate(String name, MemberListType listType, CacheType cacheType)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetPropertyCandidates(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Type[] types, Boolean allowPrefixLookup)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetPropertyImpl(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Type returnType, Type[] types, ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.PatternsModule.bindProp[a](Type tc, String propName, FSharpFunc`2 retType, FSharpFunc`2 argTypes, FSharpList`1 tyargs)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.PatternsModule.u_constSpec@1482-39.Invoke(FSharpList`1 tyargs)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.PatternsModule.u_Expr@1358-2.Invoke(BindingEnv env)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.List.map[T,TResult](FSharpFunc`2 mapping, FSharpList`1 x)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.PatternsModule.u_Expr@1358-2.Invoke(BindingEnv env)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.List.map[T,TResult](FSharpFunc`2 mapping, FSharpList`1 x)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.PatternsModule.u_Expr@1358-2.Invoke(BindingEnv env)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Primitives.Basics.List.map[T,TResult](FSharpFunc`2 mapping, FSharpList`1 x)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.PatternsModule.u_Expr@1358-2.Invoke(BindingEnv env)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.PatternsModule.u_Expr@1372-4.Invoke(BindingEnv env)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.PatternsModule.u_Expr@1380-7.Invoke(BindingEnv env)
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.PatternsModule.deserialize(Type localAssembly, Type[] referencedTypeDefs, Type[] spliceTypes, FSharpExpr[] spliceExprs, Byte[] bytes)
```

I'm getting this exception during my nightly runs, almost every night. When I run it during the day it never shows up.

Has anyone encountered this before, or does anyone have any suggestions on how to find out what causes this error?

I'm at F# 4.0. I have no idea whether this is a bug in the type provider, in F#, or something else.

**EDIT:** Unfortunately I can't post the actual code that fails, but I have created a piece of dummy code, which shows how the functions involved look. I hope this is at least to some help (for instance to show where quotations are used).

```
// Library 1
type schema = SqlDataConnection<ConnectionString = """...""", ForceUpdate = false, LocalSchemaFile = "schema.dbml">

// Library 2
module Data =
    let getData filter =
        let ctx = schema.GetDataContext()
        query {
            for row in ctx.Table do
            where ((%filter) row)
            select row) }
        |> Seq.groupBy (fun row -> row.Date)
        |> Seq.map (fun (_, rows) -> rows |> Seq.maxBy (fun row -> row.Column1))
        |> Seq.toArray

// Library 3
module Failing =
    let failingFunction () =
        let data = Data.getData <@ fun row -> // Fails on this line
            row.Column2 = "Foo" && row.Column3 = "Bar")
        ...
```

Comment: That call stack doesn't metntion an SQL Connection anywhere. Post the coded that throws this.

Comment: As for nightly runs - using what account? A type provider generates types based on what it can see. Maybe the server isn't running or the build agent's account doesn't have access to a table. When you run the code yourself, probably with `sysadmin` priviledges, you have no trouble reading all tables

Comment: Thanks for your comments @PanagiotisKanavos. Regarding the throwing code, please see my updated question. The point about users is certainly valid, although in this exact case the code is running using my own user on a virtual machine. The failing job is scheduled using Windows' Task Scheduler. When I trigger the job manually from the Task Scheduler in the morning, it passes. Everything should, as such, be exactly as it was during the night. I could understand if the exception I see is a TimeOutException or something like that, but it isn't.